# Custom product pricelists / currencies

Tags: price, currency, magento2.4.4, multicurrency

If I need to feed Magento with several **pre-calculated and fixed** product prices per currency. How can this be archived? Maybe a module?

If I have 10 languages and 5 currencies, I would end up with needing to create 50 websites to archive this natively in Magento?